# Cisco router boot error

Tags: cisco, hardware

[image: error showing]

When I start my Cisco router it shows me the attached error. What is the problem with the NVRAM of the router and how do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is exactly what is stated in the message you see: the nvram (non volatile ram) of your router is corrupted.

You need to change it.

It seems it is something quite easy to do, provide you get a replacement flash SIMM.

Cisco provide the procedure here:

[Cisco 2600 - Replacing the Internal Flash Memory SIMM](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/2600/hardware/installation/notes/2600mem.html#wp92946)

Note: in some routers the NVRAM is different from Flash. It seems in the 2600 the NVRAM is actually on the FLASH but I'm not 100% confident and don't have time right now to check it.

Comment: In a 2600 (router), the NVRAM is in the RTC. The battery on that thing is only designed for ~10 years. It also looks like flash is corrupt. He could break into ROMMON and see if it's accessible.